# pycharm unable to load django apps

Tags: python, django, pycharm

In The **PyCharm** I have **Django** configured in `virtual environment`, what I did is:

1. Previously I had python 3.6 on my windows 10 so I uninstalled it and
2. Installed Python 3.7
3. `pip install virtualenv`
4. `vertualenv venv`  and then activated it
5. `pip install django`
6. also installed `djangorestframework`, `coreapi` and `requests` via `pip`
7. `django-admin startproject hasslefreeaccounts`
8. opened project in PyCharm, then: **Files > settings > Language &
   Framework** and Configured my project as:
9. entered project root, settings.py and manage.py path *(see image below)*

[image]

and then created 2 apps named **customer** and **master** 
and then configured the run configurations as:

[image]

after this (am using pycharm professional) everything works fine except while importing apps PyCharm Gives me error when I import my django apps in other as:

```
from masters.models import some_class
```

pycharm says cant find module, thought when I run project it works fine with no error. 
so I tried doing:

```
from ..master.models import some_class
```

This makes PyCharm import apps *(see image below)*

[image]

this in pycharm doesn't shows any error but on **run** gives error as:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

### Other Details:

and here is the **project interpreter settings**:

[image]

and `Settings.py` as:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'KEY_HERE'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'customers',
    'masters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hasslefreeaccounts.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )

}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hasslefreeaccounts.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'  # 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

#### UPDATED:

Basically PyCharm is reading my apps one directory above 
I have tried updating my project source root to one directory above as well, but that doesn't help, in **project interpreter settings**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of but this helped me!

[image]

As in the image shown, the virtualenv shall be within the project directory and not outside, this helpe me!